# Helvetica font not showing up! Is my @import wrong?

Tags: css, web, font-family

Very newbie question, sorry in advance if it comes out to be a simple answer, but my Helvetica font isn't showing up. This is my code:

```
@import "..\fonts\Helvetica";
@import "..\fonts\Neue Helvetica";

body {
    background: #E1E1E1;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, serif;
}
```

It always shows up as Arial! I don't have Helvetica Neue installed on my system, even though I have the .ttf, because I wanna include it on my site and just call an import there so everyone can see it, regardless of their installation. I've got them in the same project under a different folder path as shown above. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/* These links need to point to actual ttf files and be relative to your css file */
@font-face {font-family: "Helvetica"; src: url('../fonts/Helvetica.ttf') format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf') format('truetype');}


body {
    background: #E1E1E1;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica-Neue, HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Different systems may name Helvetica Neue differently, hence the 3 directives above.  You can check using FireBug, or Chrome/Safari inspector to see which one your system recognises.

However, I suspect that what you are attempting is outside the scope of the the permitted uses of your Helvetica license.  You should consider licensing from [fonts.com](http://fonts.com).

Also, not sure why you would choose to offer serif as a fallback, since Arial and Helvetica Neue are both sans-serif fonts.

Comment: That did not work :( and about the license thing, I'm not even sure I wanna use that font anyway. Now I just really wanna solve this problem for other non-system fonts I may or may not wanna use

Comment: I'm using serif as a fallback so I can clearly see if 'Helvetica Neue' failed or not. I'm also right now using Comic Sans MS instead of Arial to make it even clearer.. lol. It's not actually gonna be serif once I finalize the styling

Comment: Edited my answer - your imports were not calling filenames.  These files need to exist on your web-server and be in a path relative to the CSS file that the @import declaration sits in.

Comment: Ermahgerd that werked. Thanks so much! Definitely keeping this one for future reference.

Comment: You can’t refer to a font file in an `@import` rule.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot legally use Helvetica as a downloadable font, and you cannot refer to a font file in an `@import`. To get started with downloadable fonts (web fonts), check out http://www.google.com/webfonts